# How to use button instead of submit in mvc4

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a form submit button and it works, but I don't want the page to refresh when the form is submitted. I have heard of a form button that won't refresh the page. How would I use this button instead of the submit button I have now. I have tried just putting it in my code instead of submit, but then nothing happens.

Please help and thank you for your time.

Here is my View:

```
 <p>
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Get))
    {
        <b>Search by:</b> @Html.RadioButton("SearchBy", "Name", true)<text> Name</text>
        @Html.RadioButton("SearchBy", "surname")<text> surname</text><br>
        @Html.TextBox("search") <input type="submit" value="Search" />
    }
</p>
```

Comment: A 'button' has got nothing to do with it. You need to use ajax to post the form if your do not want to refresh the page (for example using the [jQuery.get()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/) function).

Comment: lol ya i noticed now that why i removed my previous comment thanks for the help